# function to get the power of a number

Tags: r, multiplication, floating

looking for a way to get from an floating point number the power of 10 to which it is noted

6.45e-8 - would be 8

3.21e-4 would be 4

0.013 would be 2

or minus in all

is ther e a function which would do the following
instead of multiplying with 6.45e_8 it would be at first dividing by 1e-8 and then multiply with (6.45e-8/1e8=...).

Comment: rolled back to restore original (answered) question. Questions shouldn't undergo "fundamental" edits after they have been answered.

Comment: Here's yet another version of the question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923341/multiplication-r-without-float

Comment: they said i should do

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
floor(log10(x))
```

? `log10` computes the log base 10, `floor` finds the next smaller integer.

Comment: yes, your solution is more complete (mine does solve the OP's original stated question/set of test cases)

Answer (score 1):

```
tenexp <- function(x){c <- trunc(log10(abs(x))); return(abs(c-1*(c<0)))}
```

Here's the (desired?) result:

```
> tenexp(0.0134)
[1] 2
> tenexp(6.45e-8)
[1] 8
> tenexp(6.45e+3)
[1] 3
> tenexp(-1.28e+4)
[1] 4
```