# multiplication R without float

Tags: r, floating-point, precision

is there a way to do the multiplication with a float in a serie sof two multiplications with integers. I would need to write a function which accepts as input values such as

3.4556546e-8

1.3

0.134435

Instead of doing 100*0.134435 it would do
100/1000000
and then multiply with

134435

the function should as output just give 1000000 and 134435 - it is just needed because i need to work with some very large numbers in big integers and mutipliying with anythign except for intgers doent work

Comment: do you have a limit for how many digits to return?

Comment: to return from what?

Comment: you mean in the original numb...i would say something like 10 or 25

Comment: from the function, digits after the float.

Comment: the number which should be inputted will not have more than 15 difits...

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you want to do arbitrary precision arithmetics. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigq(0.134435)
100 * x
#Big Rational ('bigq') :
#  [1] 121088283181110525/9007199254740992
```